# Android keyboard remains same upon application launch from apps search

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Android app which has just one screen and there is **NO** edit text field in this screen( infact there is no UI elements on this screen).

When I try to search this app in Apps search by giving app name as keyword (its obvious keyboard comes out in order to type app name to search in apps tray) and after search, I clicked on my app to open/launch still the keyboard comes out and it wont go away until I press back button. When I launch my app the keyboard should not appear over there because this keyboard came from apps search. I does not look UI friendly, how can we handle this. Please share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can set in your manifest this value under your activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    ....
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
```

Or try to hide the keyboard manually in onCreate like this:

```
//kotlin
fun hideKeyboard(context:Context, view:View){
    val inputMethodManager = 
        context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken,
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY)
}
```

An call the code like this

```
hideKeyboard(this, findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content));
```

Answer (score 1):

implement this in your first activity it will hide the keyboard

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
 if (view == null) {
        view = new View(activity);
    }
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden">
</activity>
```

put this line into your manifest file in your activity tag

Answer (score 0):

The best Solution for your requirement is:-

Create a `BaseActivity` ,

> then extend all your activities to BaseActivity rather than
>   AppcompactActivity

**Then in manifest do this**

```
<activity
    android:name=".BaseActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
```

This will not Show keyboard when any of the activity loads